# Have two different background colors on input range

Tags: css, html

I'd like to have the left part of my input type:range to be #555555 and past the slider to the right to be #FFFFFF.

```css
#seekslider {
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 30px;
    left: 0px;
    right: 0px;
    height: 5px;
    -webkit-appearance: none !important;
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
}
#seekslider::-webkit-slider-thumb {
    -webkit-appearance: none !important;
    background-color: #006CD0;
    height: 13px;
    width: 13px;
    border-radius: 100%;
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<input id="seekslider" type="range" min="0.0" max="100.0" value="0" step="0.1">
```

Comment: This is not actually a duplicate of that question. I'm also looking for a differing left and right color on a range input.

Answer (score 0):

```css
#seekslider {
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 30px;
    left: 0px;
    right: 0px;
    height: 5px;
    -webkit-appearance: none !important;
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
}
#seekslider::-webkit-slider-thumb {
    -webkit-appearance: none !important;
    background-color: #006CD0;
    height: 13px;
    width: 13px;
    border-radius: 100%;
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<input id="seekslider" type="range" min="0.0" max="100.0" value="0" step="0.1">
```

```css
#seekslider {
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 30px;
    left: 0px;
    right: 0px;
    height: 5px;
    -webkit-appearance: none !important;
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
}
#seekslider::-webkit-slider-thumb {
    -webkit-appearance: none !important;
    background-color: #006CD0;
    height: 13px;
    width: 13px;
    cursor: pointer;
    position:relative;
    box-shadow: 0 0 0 red,
    -13px 0 0 red,
    -26px 0 0 red,
    -39px 0 0 red,
    -52px 0 0 red,
    -65px 0 0 red,
    -78px 0 0 red,
    -91px 0 0 red,
    -104px 0 0 red,
    -117px 0 0 red;
    z-index:2;
}
```

```html
<input id="seekslider" type="range" min="0.0" max="100.0" value="0" step="0.1">
```